# How add and read cookies from the same servlet in different

Tags: java, html, servlets, cookies

From a form (where you write age and name) in an index.html page I'm able (using POST) to call my servlet01 which tests if I'm an adult or a minor (simply writing something like out.println( "you are an adult") or out.println( "you are a minor") if age is less than...)

Now I've to change the servlet01: it should remember the same information (age and name) as cookie and: 
a) when the user is an adult the servlet01 should ask to insert also the address. The address needs to be saved on another cookie always using the servlet01 and producing a report where it shows the name, the age and the address;

b) when the user is minor servlet01 should redirect the user to servlet02. Servlet02 should read the cookies (age and name) and says "User:" + name + " of age:" + age + " you are a minor"

This is what I've done:
servlet01
http://pastebin.com/aFMSkeZ4

servlet02
http://pastebin.com/YqMZpqJd

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm finding difficulties to solve part a). I don't know how set and call a cookie from the same servlet: first time checking the parameter age and name (and setting age_cookie and name_cookie), the second time I should propose a form to insert the address and then save that parameter as cookie.. and I'm lost...

Answer (score 0):

With each [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) comes an array of [`Cookie`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) objects; You can access them using [`request.getCookies()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29).

By iterating over this array, you can find the cookie you've previously filled based on its [name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#getName%28%29), and then read its [value](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#getValue%28%29).

Setting a cookie is done by adding it to the response using [`response.addCookie(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29).

Answer (score 0):

To add a new cookie you can use a method like:

```
public void setCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    final String cookieName = "my_cool_cookie";
    final String cookieValue = "my cool value here !";  // you could assign it some encoded value
    final Boolean useSecureCookie = new Boolean(false);
    final int expiryTime = 60 * 60 * 24;  // 24h in seconds
    final String cookiePath = "/";

    Cookie myCookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
    cookie.setSecure(useSecureCookie.booleanValue());  // determines whether the cookie should only be sent using a secure protocol, such as HTTPS or SSL
    cookie.setMaxAge(expiryTime);  // A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.
    cookie.setPath(cookiePath);  // The cookie is visible to all the pages in the directory you specify, and all the pages in that directory's subdirectories
    response.addCookie(myCookie);
}
```

And to read the cookie value you can use:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
  String name = cookies[i].getName();
  String value = cookies[i].getValue();
}
```